# I get a Permission Error when I want to use 'GridSearchCV'

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, grid-search

I want to use GridSearchCV to optimize values. When I'm doing this, I get Permission Error and similar errors.

```
# Data
dataset = pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

# Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

# SVM
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(kernel='rbf', random_state=0)
```

The problem is begin after this point.

```
# Grid Search with Cross Validation (Params Optimization)
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
p = [{'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Kernel':['linear']},
     {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['rbf'],
      'gamma': [1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001]}]

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=p,
                  scoring='accuracy', cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search = gs.fit(X, y)
bestScore = grid_search.best_score_
bestParams = grid_search.best_params_
print(bestScore, bestParams)
```

The error message is as below.
This was just a part because the error was too long.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 
391, in _process_worker
call_item = call_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
File 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib
\multiprocessing\queue 
s.py", line 99, in get
    if not self._rlock.acquire(block, timeout):
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Erişim engellendi
```

Comment: get rid of `n_jobs = -1`

Comment: this did not work

Comment: Can you add the entire error stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the complete sklearn code within the following scope and try.

```
from joblib import parallel_backend

with parallel_backend('threading', n_jobs=2):
    #your sklearn code here
```

This solved my issue of `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`.